How to make a custom function called whenever a method of the PDO class is invoked
I am attempting to hook into the functions within the PDO class.
I declared the zend_execute_internal function and hooked it by setting the address of my custom function, but in the code of New Relic or Datadog, it seems they use zend_hash_str_find_ptr to perform the operation within the PHP_MINIT_FUNCTION.
However, I couldn't figure out exactly how they are hooking the functions. I've spent a month searching through a vast amount of materials, but none of the explanations worked as described.
How can I make my function execute first and then execute the original function?
Or is there a way to use symbols like in C..?
tried many approaches, but the most promising code was the one below. However, the result of zend_hash_str_find_ptr always returned NULL no matter where it was executed.
I want to create a feature that collects transactions performed by the user through PDO and displays them as statistics, unlike a custom class.
zend_class_entry *ce = zend_hash_str_find_ptr(CG(class_table), "PDO", sizeof("PDO")-1);
if (ce != NULL) {
    original = zend_hash_str_find_ptr(&ce->function_table, "exec", sizeof("exec")-1);

    if (original != NULL) {
        original_handler_pdo_exec = original->internal_function.handler;
        original->internal_function.handler = my_overwrite_pdo_exec;
    }
}


Is there a reason why you don't just create a custom class e.g. MyPDO which extends of PDO?

Unlike a custom class, I want to create a feature to collect transactions performed by the user through PDO and display them as statistics. I implemented it in C, but it seems that PHP works differently.

It could be useful to [edit] the question and add this information inside it as well

Thanks to you, I was able to ask the question more clearly

What user you are talking about?

Wouldn't it be simpler to collect this data on the database server side? Like general log in mysql?

It is targeted at businesses or users running PHP servers. I want to create a PHP agent similar to the concept of a c-agent that collects usage, data flow, etc.

PDO is a typical example, but ideally, the goal is to hook all functions that the user needs for monitoring.

I found the function uopz_set_hook that allows you to set hooks to execute when entering a function or method.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uopz-set-hook.php

Thank you for letting me know! I’ll read through it and give it a try myself. I’ll also share the results
